# Getting user information via Graph API

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to get the user's basic information in my iOS app, but when I call the method to do a graph API request I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on FBRequest.m on the line

```
if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(request:didReceiveResponse:)]
```

I have FBRequestDelegate in my header file and I'm implementing the request:didReceiveResponse: method.

Here's the code where I'm making the request

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    FBRequest *request=[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
}
```